# WebApplicationException and NotFoundException in multi-catch

Tags: java, multi-catch

So my question is this :

Basically I've a method with a try-catch block where I'm catching a WebApplicationException (javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException) but my method is throwing NotFoundException (com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException) .

so I wanted to handle both like this :

```
try {


} catch (WebApplicationException e | NotFoundException e) {


}
```

However I get the following compile-time error :

> The exception NotFoundException is already caught by the alternative
>   WebApplicationException

But why is that? NotFoundException is supposed to come from a totally different package (jersey), isn't it ?

Also - it works fine if i put them in separate catch() blocks.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the child exception first like.

```
try {

} catch (NotFoundException e) {
} catch (WebApplicationException e) {
}
```

> But why is that? NotFoundException is supposed to come from a totally
>   different package (jersey)

If you go through the `jersey's NotFoundException` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.1.5/com/sun/jersey/api/NotFoundException.java/?v=source) than you found, `NotFoundException extends WebApplicationException`. Here, `NotFoundException` inherit the `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException` class. So, `WebApplicationException` is a parent class of `com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException`, that's why you get an error.

```
package com.sun.jersey.api;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;

/**
 * A HTTP 404 (Not Found) exception.
 * 
 * @author Paul.Sandoz@Sun.Com
 */
public class NotFoundException extends WebApplicationException
```

Answer (score 0):

Your synthax is wrong. See [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html). Do this instead:

```
try {


} catch (WebApplicationException | NotFoundException e) {


}
```